# Have two buttons with the same name but only one button can active?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie with Rails and trying to make a very simple Rails program. My problem is, when I made a Rails program, at first, I created page named faction page and location page, everything seemed ok. And I created a button named faction and location, which link to location page and faction page, it was ok.

My problem is, when I tried to add a page named course, and I make a button link to another page at the left, there appear another button named faction, as you can see in the picture.

[Here is my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FypKW.png)

Here is my code in the application.html.erb

```
<body>
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="<%= root_path %>" class="brand-logo">Link toi trang</a>
  <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <a href="<%= courses_path %>" >Courses</a>
    <li><a href="<%= pages_location_path %>">trang location</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to "faction", pages_faction_path %>Faction</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav> 
<ul class="sidenav" 
id="mobile-demo">
<a href="<%= courses_path %>" >Courses</a>
<li><a href="<%= pages_location_path %>">Location</a></li>
<li><%= link_to "faction", pages_faction_path %>Faction</li> </ul>
```

And here is my code in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :courses
root 'pages#home'
get 'pages/faction'
get 'pages/location'
get 'location/faction'
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

I am very confusing with this, did I make something wrong ? Please give me some ideas. Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably some messed up html, either indentation or a no closing tag or something like that.

Comment: you have enter link_to 'faction' twice in the page. check your code